# Best batch photo upload applet

Tags: java, flash

I'm looking to handle image uploads on a site I'm building. All the behind the scenes stuff is fine, but creating an intuitive front-end is causing me head pains.

The problem with handling photos in a world where most people have asynchronous internet connections is the photos' size. I want each user to upload (at least) 10-20 images of an event. On modern cameras, 10-20 images translates to 50-200megs.

If people have 256kbps upload speed, it's already ~15 minutes just in transfer. My experience is that people are just not *that* patient when it comes to waiting for something to happen... So I need to do something about it.

I'm looking for a Flash/Java (no Silverlight, please) applet that can resize images on the **client-side** to a specified width and upload that much smaller file. If I can get images down to a few hundred KB, it might be a usable system.

Edit: This is for a personal project. The one suggestion so far is for something that costs $184. I wish I had that much disposable cash for these days! My max budget is around $40 though I'd naturally prefer something free and open source =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.jumploader.com/demo_control.html  - Free

Answer (score 2):

we use this:

http://www.aurigma.com/

runs perfactly since a few years! (both java and activex)

Comment: Yeah that's quite nice but I don't have $184 in disposable cash to lay out on this. Not your fault - I didn't specify price.

Comment: sorry oli,
but, as i was once a time told: there is no free lunch.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: http://www.jfileupload.com/products/jbatchupload/index.html

[Disclosure: This is my site]

Can upload thousands of files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

I am researching this myself.
jupload.sourceforge.net looks like one possible answer.

http://jupload.sourceforge.net/advanced_js_demo.html

mike